# pip install from a github repo - how to build C-extensions with Cython during egg install

Tags: python, git, pip, cython, egg

I can successfully install [the DMSL package](https://github.com/dasacc22/dmsl) using the following commands

```
git clone git://github.com/dasacc22/dmsl.git
cd dmsl
sudo python setup.py install
```

but when I try installing with `pip`

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/dasacc22/dmsl.git#egg=dmsl
```

I get an error

```
Obtaining dmsl from git+git://github.com/dasacc22/dmsl.git#egg=dmsl
  Updating /Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/test/src/dmsl clone
  Running setup.py egg_info for package dmsl
    
    warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'daml'
    warning: no files found matching '*.daml' under directory 'daml'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory 'daml'
Installing collected packages: dmsl
  Running setup.py develop for dmsl
    
    warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'daml'
    warning: no files found matching '*.daml' under directory 'daml'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory 'daml'
    building 'dmsl.cdoc' extension
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/include/python2.7 -c dmsl/cdoc.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/dmsl/cdoc.o
    i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: dmsl/cdoc.c: No such file or directory
    i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/test/bin/python -c "import setuptools; __file__='/Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/test/src/dmsl/setup.py'; exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps:
    running develop

running egg_info

writing dmsl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to dmsl.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to dmsl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing dmsl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to dmsl.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to dmsl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'dmsl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'daml'
warning: no files found matching '*.daml' under directory 'daml'
warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory 'daml'

writing manifest file 'dmsl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext

building 'dmsl.cdoc' extension

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/include/python2.7 -c dmsl/cdoc.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/dmsl/cdoc.o

i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: dmsl/cdoc.c: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/test/bin/python -c "import setuptools; __file__='/Users/andrei/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/test/src/dmsl/setup.py'; exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/andrei/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I fix this?

---

#### EDIT1:

I have forked the repo and corrected `MANIFEST.in` so in my repo it has

```
recursive-include dmsl *.html *.dmsl *.c
```

and it finds *.html and *.dmsl, but the problem is that there are no *.c files, which I need to create with `Cython`. I have the package installed, but being a python-newbie I need to be guided for the next step. What should I do to produce the C-files? Do I need to add something else to `MANIFEST.in` or to `setup.py`?

---

#### EDIT2:

I've got some help on freenode#python. Guys suggest to produce the C-files with `python setup.py build_ext` and add them to the repo. It would be nice to avoid this. Is there a way to run build_ext command automatically with `pip install`?

---

Just for information: it is worth to visit freenode#pip for such questions. There you may have a luck to find [jezdez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153296/jezdez) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing Pyrex the installation worked for me. You might want to add Cython and Pyrex to the installed_requires parameter of the setup() call.